# executing the codes inside the subfolders

Tags: python, bash, shell, for-loop

I have sub-folders(data1,data2,data3) inside a folder(Data) and the python(.py) programs are present inside all the sub-folders with same name. I want to run these python programme in each folder.

```
Data
    data1/a.py
    data1/b.py
    data1/c.py
    
    data2/a.py
    data2/b.py
    data2/c.py
    
    data3/a.py
    data3/b.py
    data3/c.py
```

I tried the code below:

```
 for dir in Data/*
 do
 cd $dir
 python *.py
 done
```

But it doesn't execute the code inside the sub-folder,can anybody suggest a proper solution for the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can run multiple Python scripts with one command. But you can use a second `for` loop to achieve this.

Another issue is that you need to `cd` back up to the parent directory before the next loop iteration starts; `pushd` and `popd` are a nice solution to this.

```
for dir in Data/*
do
  pushd $dir
  for script in *.py
  do
    python $script
  done
  popd
done
```

Answer (score 3):

Don't do this with loops.  Assuming you want to run *all* python scripts in and below `Data/`, and you want those scripts executed with the current working directory equal to the directory in which the script is found, use:

```
find Data -name '*.py' -execdir ./{} \;
```

If you don't want to execute all scripts, filter the `find` appropriately.

For example, if you just want to run scripts name `a.py`, `b.py`, or `c.py`, you might use:

```
find Data -name '[abc].py' -execdir ./{} \;
```

If you have poorly named directories, you might also want to use `-type f` to avoid attempting to execute a directory named `a.py`. eg `find Data -type f -name '[abc].py' -execdir ./{} \;`

You can trivially limit the scope by specifying directories: `find Data/data1 Data/data3 ...` or `find Data/data[12] ...` or `find Data/data[13] ...` all work as expected.

Comment: can the script inside the subfolders be executed and saved the output in the same subfolder insted of pwd

Comment: With `-execdir`, the script will run from the directory, so any output will be written to paths relative to that.  You won't be able to do `>` type redirections directly, but you can do `find ... -execdir sh -c './$1 > output' _ {} \;` to let the shell parse redirections.

Answer (score 1):

I don't use `python` so fwiw ...

Assumptions:

- `python` can work with a directory/path being part of the input
- we're sitting in the parent directory of `Data`
- we want to execute all `*.py` scripts located (somewhere) under `Data`

One idea to streamline the operation:

```
while read -r script
do
    python "${script}"
done < <(find Data -type f -name "*.py")
```

Alternatively, limiting ourselves to specific subdirectories:

```
for script in Data/data{1..3}/*.py
do
    python "${script}"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is subshells.

You are `cd`-ing into the first directory, and then probably getting an error on the next because it doesn't exist. *i.e.*, the first iteration you `cd data1/` and none of the others are subdirectories of that.

Assume your structure is under `/tmp/`. you are logged to `/tmp/Data` and run your script. The first loop executes `cd data1/`, so you are now logged to `/tmp/Data/data1/`. Let's skip the execution for now...

The next iteration issues `cd data2/`, which does not exist as a subdirectory of `/tmp/Data/data1`, so it fails, and at that point you should *hope* that `python *.py` will fail, or is at least harmlessly idempotent...

So let's try a simple fix. Assuming you are logged to the directory whre the `Data` subdirectory exists,

```
for this in Data/*/*.py; do # iterate over the *scripts*
  ( cd "${this%/*}/" && python "$this" )
done
```

When the subshell exits, the parent is still logged to the directory where `Data` is. Only the subshell did the `cd`.

Or if the scripts don't *require* you be logged to that directory,

```
for this in Data/*/*.py; do python "$this"; done
```

That work for you?